# How to get data in a single array

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

How can i get this data in a single array using loop?

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,1,23,5,2 [1] => 1,1,1,2,3,2 [2] => 2,3,4 [3] => 1,2,3 [4] => 1,2,3,4 [5] => 1,2,3,10 [6] => 1,2,3,4 [7] => 1,2,3 [8] => 3,2,2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without loop

```
$flattenArray = array_merge([], ...$arrays);
```

use `array_unique()` to remove duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

**It a use of [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:**